# SQL query to get quarter and month/year from date

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

In a column I have dates - `01-02-2022, 01-03-2022`

How can i get this in the below format

```
ABS_DATE                    Quarter            Month 
01-02-2022                  Q1 2022             02/2022
30-03-2021                  Q1 2021             03/2021
29-12-2020                  Q4 2020             12/2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `to_char()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F) to convert your dates to whatever [format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A) you need, including quarters:

```
to_char(abs_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') as abs_date
to_char(abs_date, '"Q"Q YYYY') as quarter
to_char(abs_date, 'MM/YYYY') as month
```

The quoted `"Q"` is [a character literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A), not to be confused with the unquoted `Q` which is the element for "Quarter of year".

Demo using a CTE for sample data:

```
with your_table (abs_date) as (
  select date '2022-02-01' from dual
  union all
  select date '2021-03-30' from dual
  union all
  select date '2020-12-29' from dual
)
select abs_date as raw_date,
  to_char(abs_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') as abs_date,
  to_char(abs_date, '"Q"Q YYYY') as quarter,
  to_char(abs_date, 'MM/YYYY') as month
from your_table
```

| RAW_DATE | ABS_DATE | QUARTER | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-FEB-22 | 01-02-2022 | Q1 2022 | 02/2022 |
| 30-MAR-21 | 30-03-2021 | Q1 2021 | 03/2021 |
| 29-DEC-20 | 29-12-2020 | Q4 2020 | 12/2020 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0d861fb82969c8dd020ddac214102c1d)